# How can I get a default value in a dropdown using form API?

Tags: 7, forms

```php
$results = db_select('users', 'u')->fields('u', ['name', 'uid', 'mail'])->execute();
$options = [];
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $options[$result->uid] = $result->name . ' | ' . $result->mail;
}
unset($options[array_search(0, $options)]);
$form['user'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('Select User'),
  '#options' => $options,
  '#default_value' => ('select a value'),
  '#states' => [
    'visible' => [
      ':input[name="data_set"]' => ['value' => 'education'],
    ],
  ],
];
$form['submit'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Expire'),
];
```

I have this dropdown , how can I get the default value like `Select a value` or something

Answer (score 0):

For required items a `-select-` item is added automatically. If the form field is not a required one, you'll have to add it manually, for example with the following code.

```
  $options = array('_none' => '-select item-') + $options; //Places an extra option at the start
```

If it's the first item it should be selected automatically but if you want to be safe.

```
  // Use the array key, not the value.
  '#default_value' => '_none',
```

You'll have to filter it out the '_none' value in the submit handler afterwards.

Comment: Sorry @Suranga, I did not get your answer, should I use `Soptions=array('_none'=>'select item-') + $options;`? or `#default_value=>'_none'`?

Comment: You need to use both.